# corda M13.0 - Integration Testing of an Oracle

Tags: corda

I followed the oracle-example to create a dummy FX rate oracle.  It passed the MockNetwork tests.  Now in the integration test via driver, I get the following FlowSessionException complaining "flow has not been registered". 
My other integration tests don't need to register any flows.  Is it peculiar to the oracle service?
How do I register an initiating flow in the test?

```
net.corda.core.flows.FlowSessionException: Party CN=FX Rate Oracle,O=FX Rate Oracle,L=San Francisco,C=US,OU=argent.fxrate_oracle rejected session request: argent.flow.FXRateQueryFlow has not been registered
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.waitForConfirmation(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:266) ~[corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.startNewSession(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:326) ~[corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.sendAndReceive(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:169) ~[corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.FlowStateMachine$DefaultImpls.sendAndReceive$default(FlowStateMachine.kt:22) ~[corda-core-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.sendAndReceive(FlowLogic.kt:89) ~[corda-core-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at argent.flow.FXRateQueryFlow.call(FXRateQueryFlow.kt:20) ~[service-interface-0.1.jar:?]
    at argent.flow.FXRateQueryFlow.call(FXRateQueryFlow.kt:14) ~[service-interface-0.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:107) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:39) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1067) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:767) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar:0.7.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:69) [corda-node-0.13.0.jar:?]
```

Comment: Have you annotated the corresponding flow to `FXRateQueryFlow` with `@InitiatedBy(FXRateQueryFlow.class)`?

Comment: Can you paste your flow code here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer to my own question.  But the fix seems to be moving the QueryHandler class out of the object wrapper into a standalone class file.
That is not necessary for many of our other InitiatedBy flow and they seem to self-register properly.  Only the flow included in the same object wrapper as the @CordaService class does not seem to be able to self-register.

Seems to a bug to me.

\Sean

Comment: Thanks for this - we'll double check it and post a fix if necessary!